# webcam Unable to find a compatible palette format

Tags: ubuntu, webcam

I just bought a new webcam and attach it with Ubuntu Desktop, then Run a command to install it

```
sudo apt-get install fswebcam
```

when I entered this command to take an image,

```
fswebcam image.jpg
```

it shows me an error

```
--- Opening /dev/video0...
Trying source module v4l2...
/dev/video0 opened.
No input was specified, using the first.
Unable to find a compatible palette format.
```

Can you please guide me to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that unplugging the webcam and reconnecting it got it working again. It seemed to fail after I performed a firmware update and installed some packages but my cron job for fswebcam is now working again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can look at this discussion on [ArchLinux.](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=132272)
It might help you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need the video4linux support libraries. Check if you have them already.

```
locate v4l1compat.so
```

In my case, the output is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so`, yours might be different if you're on 32bit.

If it't not there, just install it:

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-0
```

and try to locate it again.

Try to launch cheese with preloading the library

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/your-path-to-lib/v4l1compat.so fswebcam test.jpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the external webcam changed from /dev/video1 to /dev/video0 for no apparent reason. This might be because the laptop's internal webcam decided to turn off unexpectedly.

[Specifying the device with -d as described here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/fswebcam.1.html) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was simple access issue, the `motion` user that was running the process did not have access to the support libraries.
On raspbian it is located here: `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libv4l`. This folder contains v4l1compat.so  and v4l2convert.so.
So either running the process with `sudo` or giving access for the technical user worked.